# Azure: Can an event grid trigger a durable function?

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azure-eventgrid

My **Durable Function** to be invoked by an event grid trigger.
Looks like there's no option. Any alternatives?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please state what you've tried and any errors you got so that the community can assist better!

Comment: Currently we have event grid trigger function. But the functionality of a function is not sufficient, we need durable function capability, but durable functions doesn't have event grid trigger.

Comment: Is this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-event-publishing?tabs=csharp-script) helpful?

Comment: I went through this, it talks about how to publish events from Durable Function to the event grid; not how to consume an event from event grid to durable function. Thanks anyways!

Comment: In Durable Function, Starter Function can be any trigger. In your case, it is event grid trigger. Similar info on this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: Actually, there are 3 parts in Durable Functions such as Starter, Orchestration and Activity where the starter function would be the event grid trigger in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below findings helpful to the requirement:

There are 3 parts of Durable Functions such as Starter, Orchestration and Activity where the Starter function would be the event grid trigger in your case.

I have found the sample code for consuming the Event grid events given by GitHub Docs where you can use the consume events code in Activity Functions.

There is a class `EventGridConsumer` which consumed the events published by the Event Grid Trigger. As you didn't mention the runtime stack, you're using the Azure Durable Functions, I've found the Sample code of consuming the Events using Azure Function code in Node JS and C#.

NodeJS:

```
git clone git@github.com:Azure-Samples/event-grid-node-publish-consume-events.git
```

CSharp:

```
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/tree/master/EventGridConsumer/EventGridConsumer
```

References:

1. [GitHub Doc](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/blob/master/EventGridConsumer/EventGridConsumer/Function1.cs) on cSharp Code of consuming event grid evens in Azure Functions.
2. [GitHub Article](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-node-publish-consume-events) on consuming event grid events using Node JS in Azure Functions.